# How to update class initializer?

Tags: ios, swift

I have class ProgressBarLabelValues with class initializer.

```
class ProgressBarLabelValues {

    var stepsLeft: Double
    var stepsRight: Double
    var weightLeft: Double
    var weightRight: Double
    var distanceLeft: Double
    var distanceRight: Double


    init(stepsLeft: Double, stepsRight: Double, weightLeft:Double, weightRight: Double, distanceLeft:Double, distanceRight: Double){
        self.stepsLeft = stepsLeft
        self.stepsRight = stepsRight
        self.weightLeft = weightLeft
        self.weightRight = weightRight
        self.distanceLeft = distanceLeft
        self.distanceRight = distanceRight
    }
}

var progressBarLabelValues = ProgressBarLabelValues(
    stepsLeft: 0.0,
    stepsRight: goal.steps,
    weightLeft: goal.weight-5,
    weightRight: goal.weight,
    distanceLeft: 0,
    distanceRight: goal.distance)
```

anyway, the goals are set in the Goal class:

```
class Goal {

    var steps:Double
    var weight:Double
    var distance:Double

    init(steps:Double, weight: Double, distance: Double){
        self.steps = steps
        self.weight = weight
        self.distance = distance
    }
}


var goal = Goal(
    steps: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("GoalSteps"),
    weight:NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("GoalWeight"),
    distance: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("GoalDistance")    
)
```

My problem is that when I update the goal for steps             `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(10000, forKey: "GoalSteps")`

progressBarLabelValues.stepsRight does not update in the ViewController.
It doesn't notice that goal.steps have been changed. If the variable goal was a function I could ask it to update by the code goal(). Is it possible to ask the variable goal(class initializer) to update like a function?
Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- progressBarLabelValues is a *variable*
- This is not a tuple, it's just a normal class initializer

```swift
ProgressBarLabelValues(
    stepsLeft: 0.0,
    stepsRight: goal.steps,
    weightLeft: goal.weight-5,
    weightRight: goal.weight,
    distanceLeft: 0,
    distanceRight: goal.distance)
```

Looks like you forgot to call `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()` to save your changes:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setDouble(10000, forKey: "GoalSteps")
defaults.synchronize()
```

**EDIT:** The problem you're facing is that you only read from NSUserDefaults when you create your `goal` object. When you need to change its value just access to that property with:

```
goal.steps = 1000
```

This will change the content of your model object in memory. I strongly recommend you to read this section of Apple's Swift book on [Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

**EDIT 2:** The best way to solve your problem is that every time you access your setter, you save to NSUserDefaults. Maybe this is hitting the disk too much, you need to consider that. A complete listing you can try in a Playground:

```swift
import Foundation

class ProgressBarLabelValues {

    var stepsLeft: Double
    var stepsRight: Double
    var weightLeft: Double
    var weightRight: Double
    var distanceLeft: Double
    var distanceRight: Double


    init(stepsLeft: Double, stepsRight: Double, weightLeft:Double, weightRight: Double, distanceLeft:Double, distanceRight: Double){
        self.stepsLeft = stepsLeft
        self.stepsRight = stepsRight
        self.weightLeft = weightLeft
        self.weightRight = weightRight
        self.distanceLeft = distanceLeft
        self.distanceRight = distanceRight
    }
}
class Goal {
    var _steps: Double = 0
    var steps:Double {
        get {
            return self._steps
        }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(newValue, forKey: "GoalSteps")
            self._steps = newValue
        }
    }
    var weight:Double = 10
    var distance:Double = 10

    init(steps:Double, weight: Double, distance: Double){
        self.steps = steps
        self.weight = weight
        self.distance = distance
    }
}


var goal = Goal(
    steps: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("GoalSteps"),
    weight:NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("GoalWeight"),
    distance: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("GoalDistance")
)

var progressBarLabelValues = ProgressBarLabelValues(
    stepsLeft: 0.0,
    stepsRight: goal.steps,
    weightLeft: goal.weight-5,
    weightRight: goal.weight,
    distanceLeft: 0,
    distanceRight: goal.distance)



goal.steps = 1000
```

Comment: I tried that but did not help, thanks for pointing out that it is a variable.

Comment: Add code from progressBarLabelValues, so we can help